# Multiple forces in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hi I have the following graph.The rectangles represent groups where the nodes inside or on the border of the rectangle are restricted to that rectangle. I am using d3 force layout to layout the nodes but then restrict them to the bounding rectangles in the **tick**.

What I need is,
1. One force layout to handle the nodes as they currently do
2. A second force layout that handles the rectangles in the graph, so that rectangles don't overlap with each other.

It would be an added bonus if the rectangles could also be stopped from overlapping with nodes that are outside the rectangles to avoid confusion.

Can anyone point me to an example that does something similar or code something up quickly to demonstrate how this can be achieved.

Thanks. [image]

Comment: I love d3.js :) please post example to the jsfiddle.net

Comment: The example is at the moment difficult to transfer as there is a lot of data driven structures in there. If really needed I will have to do a a lot of simplification to create a jsfiddle. But, for now does anyone have any ideas or example of how to use the two forces here?

Comment: Well it's even more difficult to help you without live example.. we can speculate forever and ever what is wrong.. and jsfiddle has d3.js support.